# git-svn checkout project not working with -s

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm trying to checkout an SVN repo via `git-svn` and am having issues getting git to play nice with trunk/branches/tags directories.

This works fine:

```
git svn clone https://svn-repo-base/projects/path/to/my/project/trunk
```

however when I try:

```
git svn clone -s --no-minimize-url https://svn-repo-base/projects/path/to/my/project/
```

I just get an empty directory with no files cloned.  (the `--no-minimize-url` is there because git was trying to do a checkout on `https://svn-repo-base/` without it)

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `git svn init` and subsequent `git svn fetch` rather than `git svn clone`. This approach is far more stable than `git svn clone`
2. If your Subversion repository follows the standard Subversion `/trunk`, `/branches`, `/tags` scheme, the `-s` switch should just work. Ommit the tailing `/trunk/` in your URL:

   ```
   git svn init -s https://svn-repo-base/projects/path/to/my/project project.git
   git svn fetch
   ```
3. For me `svn fetch` aborted quite often but continues seamlessly on recalling it again. Therefore I even wrote a whole script which updates/refetches all Git-on-SVN reposities using  a Windows Batchfile. I use this `git-fetch-all` everyday to fetch all latest SVN Commits from all git repositories (in directories named .git):

   ```
   @Echo Off

   IF "%1"=="" GOTO noparams

   IF "%1"=="fetch" GOTO fetch

   goto end

   :fetch
   IF NOT exist .git\svn\refs\remotes goto nosvnwc
   git svn fetch
   if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto fetch
   git svn rebase -l
   goto end

   :nosvnwc
   ECHO --- Directory seems not to be a SVN bound Git Repository. Doing plain fetch 
   git fetch --all
   goto end

   :noparams
   FOR /d %%f IN (.\*.git) DO (
   cd %%f
   ECHO --- Fetching %%f SVN Commits ------------------------------------------
   call ..\%0 fetch
   ECHO --- Calling 'git gc --auto' in %%f 
   git gc --auto
   cd ..
   ECHO --- Leaving %%f
   ECHO.
   ECHO.
   )

   :end
   ECHO Update finished.
   ```